# How can I produce a statically linked Haskell binary with stack?

Tags: haskell, stackage

I want to build a static binary executable for a Haskell (it is important not to depend on any system libraries in my case). I use stack as my preferred build tool. Which flags should be set to achieve this? Bonus points for a brief explanation of each one.

Comment: As the ghc provides it's runtime to each executable statically by default, you should be fine, if you use no FFI-bindings to external libraries.

Comment: Except for libgmp. IIRC that one is always dynamically linked. You can [link that one statically too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539857/statically-link-gmp-to-an-haskell-application-using-ghc-llvm).

Comment: You can also avoi dusing libgmp entirely, but that takes a specially compiled ghc.

Comment: You should also be aware that even programs statically linked against glibc still have runtime dependencies on system files for things like locales and `dlopen`.

Comment: While googling the same problem, i found both your question and this answer: https://ro-che.info/articles/2015-10-26-static-linking-ghc. I haven't had a chance to try it out, though.